# setting environment variable in eclipse for solr

Tags: solr

Hello I am trying to run solr from eclipse. I understand that we need to set up the solr home.
If I use the `web.xml` to set up it works

```
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

But if I try to use the same from eclipse it fails by setting the Runtime->Tomcat Configuration->Environment or Runtime->Tomcat Configuration->Argument VM Arguments.
I used -Dsolr.data.dir=/home/test/test 
May I know why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable that you need to set is `-Dsolr.solr.home`. Looks like you're setting  the `-Dsolr.data.dir` variable in eclipse, which is the location where you want to put the index. That kind of configuration works if you have a placeholder like this

```
<dataDir>${solr.data.dir}</dataDir>
```

in your `solrconfig.xml`, but anyway you need to set the `solr_home` first.